# How to test a Rest Service with Spring Security on Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, junit4

I am working on a project that involves creating a rest service on Spring Boot that will eventually work with an Angular Web App and Discord Bot.

I am currently working on the backend and trying to unit test the endpoints. As evenually non-logged in users can make only make GET request. However, for some reason when ever I unit test an endpoint, it comes back as error 403. Even when I tell Spring Security to allow any request.

Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    //http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/*").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    //      .authorizeRequests()
    //          .antMatchers("/api/**/rule","/api/**/rules" )
    //              .permitAll()
    //              .anyRequest()
    //              .permitAll()
    //      .and()
    //          .formLogin()
    //              .loginPage("/login")
    //              .permitAll()
    //      .and()
    //          .logout()
    //              .permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureAuth(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN", "USER", "EDITOR").and()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER", "EDITOR");
}



    }
```

JUnit test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestSFRuleController {

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


@Autowired
MockMvc mvc;

@Autowired
SFRuleRepo repo;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    repo.deleteAll();

}

@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "admin")
public void testInsertNewRule() throws Exception {
    SFRule rule = new SFRule("test insert rule", "test desc");
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(rule);
    mvc.perform(
            post(StarfinderController.PREFIX_URL + StarfinderController.RULE_URL)
            .content(json))
            .andExpect(status()
                    .isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").isNotEmpty())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("test insert rule"));

}

}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/sf")
public class StarfinderController {


@Autowired
SFRuleRepo ruleRepo;

public static final String PREFIX_URL = "/api/sf";

public static final String RULE_URL = "/rule";
public static final String RULES_URL = "/rules";

public static final String RULE_REPO = "RULE";


public static final String PAGE = "page";
public static final String COUNT = "count";

@GetMapping(RULE_URL)
public Rule getRule(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name) {

    return ruleRepo.findByName(name);

}

@GetMapping(RULES_URL)
public List<Rule> getRules(@RequestParam(value = "tag", required = false, defaultValue = "") String tagName,
        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) int page,
        @RequestParam(value = "count", required = false) int count) {

    if (!tagName.isEmpty()) {
        // noop

    } else {
        //TODO: add support for page and count

        List<Rule> list = new LinkedList<Rule>();
        list.addAll(ruleRepo.findAll());
        return list;
    }

    return null;

}

@PostMapping(RULE_URL)
public Rule addRule(SFRule rule) {
    return ruleRepo.save(rule);
}

@PutMapping(RULE_URL)
public Rule updateRule(SFRule rule) {
    Optional<SFRule> savedRule = ruleRepo.findById(rule.getId());

    if (savedRule.isPresent()) {
        SFRule sv = savedRule.get();
        sv.setName(rule.getName());
        sv.setDesc(rule.getDesc());
        return ruleRepo.save(sv);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}

@DeleteMapping(RULE_URL)
public void deleteRule(SFRule rule) {
    ruleRepo.delete(rule);
}

}
```

Comment: How about `http.authorizeRequests().permitAll().and().authorizeRequests()..anyRequest()..authenticated()`?

Comment: Can you show the controller?

Comment: Added Controller code by request.

Also, if spring security was set so that given any request, permit it. Then why do I still get a 403 error code from JUnit? 

Because wouldn't that config basically turn off all denying of web pages?

Comment: Turns out, I configure my controller wrong as it wasn't using the url I thought it was. I thought putting in a variable for RestController also included a RequestMapping for controller. But wasn't the case

it is now able to do GET requests, but when testing for POST it doesn't seem to work. With the same error code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just put the URL in `.antMatcher().permitAll()`

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/targetURL/**").permitAll()     
}
```